# clone or append a variable in a new div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, clone

I have this Html `<h1 class="count" role="status">Search results 546</h1>`

I'm trying to clone only the numerical '546' of that div and display it inside another div 'h2.count'

I manage to call only the numerical value in an alert via:

```
var price = $('h1.count').text();
var parsedPrice = parseFloat(price.replace(/([^0-9\.])/g, ''));
     alert(parsedPrice.toFixed(0));
```

Otherwise , when i try to make it display in the div h2.count instead of an alert, it is not working.

I have try the below:

```
var price = $('h1.count').text();
var parsedPrice = parseFloat(price.replace(/([^0-9\.])/g, ''));
$parsedPrice.appendTo('h2.onlycount');
```

Any thought of what i am doing wrong ?

Thanks a lot guys !

Comment: Your `h1` doesn't have a `count` class.

Comment: sorry forgot but it does have the count class in h1, it display in the alert. i dont manage to cline it in another div . .

Comment: Can you make a working snippet using `<>` to demonstrate your issue?

Comment: $parsedPrice doesn't exist (and parsedPrice is a float with no appendTo()). You'll want something roughly like $('<span />').text(parsedPrice).appendTo('h2.onlycount') but that'll give you an extra span element wrapping the count.

Comment: Or you could simply do: $('h2.onlycount').text(parsedPrice) if you only want the price in there.

Comment: Or `$('h2.onlycount').append(parsedPrice)` if you want to append in `h2`

Answer (score 0):

I guess that your two html elements are unique so, using id's instead of classes (and native js), try this :

**html :**

```
<h1 id="count">Search results 541</h1>
<h2 id="onlycount"></h2>
```

**js :**

```
var price = document.getElementById('count').innerText;
var parsedPrice = parseFloat(price.replace(/([^0-9\.])/g, ''));
document.getElementById('onlycount').innerText = parsedPrice;
```

**https://jsfiddle.net/f3rj2bnv/**

And if you want to keep on using jQuery (replace "#" with "." if you want or have to use classes instead of ids in your html elements) :

```
var price = $('h1#count').text();
var parsedPrice = parseFloat(price.replace(/([^0-9\.])/g, ''));
$('h2#onlycount').text(parsedPrice)
```

Answer (score 0):

The content used by `.appendTo()` should be

> "a selector expression or as markup created on the fly"

Since in your example neither is true, try this:

```js
var price = $('h1.count').text();
var parsedPrice = parseFloat(price.replace(/([^0-9\.])/g, ''));
$('h2.onlycount').text(parsedPrice);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1 class="count" role="status">Search results 546</h1>
<h2 class="onlycount" role="status"></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can use [`text(function)`](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function)

```js
$('h2.onlycount').text(function(_, existingText){
   return existingText + $('h1.count').text().replace(/([^0-9\.])/g, '');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="count" role="status">Search results 546</h1>
<h2 class="onlycount"></h2>
```